# as2 to as3 swap depth movieclips?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have two movieclips on stage and I want to change which mc appear in front of another 
I've read and there are two ways for that setChildIndex and swapChildren methods but in all the tutorials I've read about is you can change the depths if they are in a sprite but I cannot use sprite 
how can I do it with movieclips???

Comment: thanks but I found out that my problem is using fullscreen
my goal is 2 mc 2 buttons 
if btn 1 is clicked mc1 fullscreen and mc2 appears at the right bottom corner on top of mc1
if btn 2 is clicked mc2 fullscreen and mc1 appears at the right bottom corner on top of mc2

Answer (score 2):

This would be the same for MovieClips as well. the two methods you mentioned, setChildIndex() and swapChildren() are methods of DisplayObjectContainer and work with DisplayObjects as the arguments. Since both MovieClip and Sprite inherit from DisplayObject, both will work identically.

These are both correct:

```
stage.swapChildren(mySprite1, mySprite2);
stage.swapChildren(myMovieClip1, myMovieClip2);
```

As are these:

```
stage.setChildIndex(mySprite, 1);
stage.setChildIndex(myMovieClip, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try casting the target as a movie clip -

```
my_movie_clip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, manageMouseOver, false, 0, true);


function manageMouseOver(event:MouseEvent):void{
     stage.setChildIndex(MovieClip(event.target), stage.numChildren - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Um MovieClip inherits from Sprite so yes anything a Sprite can do a MovieClip can do it also Not the other way around. 
Just look at the top of the docs for inheritance

[MovieClip Docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6)

Comment: thanks but I found out that my problem is also using fullscreen and I believe that wont work

ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/swapChildren()
 at smgPlayercs5_fla::MainTimeline/setFullscreen()
 at smgPlayercs5_fla::MainTimeline/full()
 at flash.display::Stage/set_displayState()
 at flash.display::Stage/set displayState()
 at smgPlayercs5_fla::MainTimeline/goFullScreen()
 at smgPlayercs5_fla::MainTimeline/goLiveFullScreen()